# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './config/secrets.json'

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am working on a git clone with a co-worker and I am fairly new to coding, so pardon my novice. I opened a git clone and when I try to run npm run serve, I get a no such file or directory open.

I have tried deleting the package-lock.json as well as the node-modules, then restarting with npm install and then npm cache clean,then
npm install -g npm,then npm install,Finally
ng serve --o

as well as various other methods including renaming the file, but I do not understand where I have gone wrong. Here is some code. Thank you for your time

```
[0] node:internal/fs/utils:344
[0]     throw err;
[0]     ^
[0]
[0] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './config/secrets.json'
[0]     at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
[0]     at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jlemke\JL Code\service-field-report\app.js:10:29)
[0]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
[0]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
[0]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
[0]     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
[0]     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
[0]   errno: -4058,
[0]   syscall: 'open',
[0]   code: 'ENOENT',
[0]   path: './config/secrets.json'
[0] }
```

Comment: Does the file exist at the path indicated (i.e., `C:\Users\jlemke\JL Code\service-field-report\config\secrets.json`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common model for working with version control, where secret information like passwords etc is kept and distributed separately.

Most likely if you look in `.gitignore` you will see `config/secrets.json` listed as not to be included in the project.

You might be able to work round this by creating an empty `config/secrets.json` file - but more likely you will need to get this file (or the contents) direct from your co-worker.

Comment: Thank you for the accurate response. This is true, he did include config/secrets.json in the gitignore. However there is nothing different in our code, so I am a tad confused as to why I received the error. I have the same secrets.json file as him and have even tried configuring it to my workplaces ip address. Thank you once again

Comment: Just guessing, but is he developing on Linux and you on Windows? The path `./config/secrets.json` looks like a Linux path, whereas on Windows it would be more like `config\secrets.json`. If you can find the `open` line in the code, try wrapping the filename with `path.normalize()`

Comment: The problem was I did not install the dependencies with npm i and npm build. Anyways, thank you for the help, that was very useful.